# Обработка кликов пользователя по кнопкам

Tags: html, golang

Всем привет
Хочу сделать на html странице 2 кнопки и, чтобы, когда пользователь нажимает на одну из них, то на странице появлялись одни данные, а когда на другу кнопку, то другие данные. Главное чтобы не было javascript-a. Возможно ли сделать это  только используя html и golang. Я сделал html разметку

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/static/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="buttons">
        <input type="submit" name="podcasts" title="Подкасты" value="Подкасты"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="articles" title="Статьи" value="Статьи">
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Тeперь не понимаю как мне передать в golang что именно нажал пользователь.
Знаю о `template.ParseForm(<formname>)`, но вроде как это подходит для того чтобы инпуты типа text обрабатывать. А как клик по кнопке обработать?

UPD:

Повесить на эти кнопки ссылки сносный подход или есть получше?

Comment: На enSO есть [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680160/how-can-i-tell-which-button-was-clicked-in-a-php-form-submit) о том, как отловить нажатую `submit` кнопку. Думаю в этом случае разница с `php` роли играть не будет.

Comment: @nazarpunk а что за issets?

Comment: @nazarpunk нашел инфу, буду пробовать

Comment: [isset](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.isset.php) проверяет установлена ли переменная.

Comment: @nazarpunk не олчилось применить. Не вижу чтото в go такого. Есть аналогичные действия, но они не работают

Comment: Плохо [искали](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16512009/how-to-extract-the-post-arguments-in-go-server). Также можете использовать [formaction](http://htmlbook.ru/html/button/formaction).

Answer (score 1):

конечно, лучше бы разнести шаблоны для подкастов и статьей. Но я все сделал в одном шаблоне для демонстрации

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    {{ if not .}}
        <div> not nil  </div>
    {{ else }}
    {{range .Data}}
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        {{ if .Name -}}
            <td class="name">{{ .Name }}</td>
            </br>
        {{ else }}
            <div></div>
        {{- end -}}
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    {{end}}
    {{end}}
    <form method="POST" action="/data">
        <div class="buttons">
            <input type="submit" name="podcasts" title="Подкасты" value="Подкасты"><br>
            <input type="submit" name="articles" title="Статьи" value="Статьи">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

`{{ if not .}}` -  если не nil

`{{range .Data}}` - foreach

когда нажимаете на кнопку, то отправляется запрос на ручку `/data`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func podcastHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    data := []struct {
        Name string
    }{
        {
            "podcast 1",
        },
        {
            "podcast 2",
        },
    }

    renderTemplate(w, r, data)
}

func articlesHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    data := []struct {
        Name string
    }{
        {
            "article 1",
        },
        {
            "article 2",
        },
    }

    renderTemplate(w, r, data)
}

func formHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if err := r.ParseForm(); err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "ParseForm() err: %v", err)
        return
    }

    value := ""
    for _, v := range r.Form {
        value = v[0]
    }

    switch value {
    case "Подкасты":
        podcastHandler(w, r)
    case "Статьи":
        articlesHandler(w, r)
    default:
        renderTemplate(w, r, "NO DATA")
    }
}

func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    renderTemplate(w, r, nil)
}

func renderTemplate(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, data interface{}) {
    t, err := template.ParseFiles("./html.html")
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    tmplContext := struct {
        Data interface{}
    }{data}

    err = t.Execute(w, tmplContext)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", indexHandler)
    http.HandleFunc("/data", formHandler)

    fmt.Printf("Starting server at port 8080\n")
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```